# What is the difference between cwd and pwd?

Tags: pwd, cwd

What is the difference between cwd and pwd?

I've tried googling it, and one of the answers mentioned that depending on some factor (which I sadly do not remember), the implementation (the code I'm assuming) is not the same? I don't suppose this is like the difference between `print('x')` vs `return str(x)` (to use a Python analogy)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- cwd: current working directory (a concept, state, or value)
- `pwd`: print working directory (a command)

Part of the confusion may be that in some shells `$PWD` is actually the current working directory name, and `pwd` is a command to display it (similar to `echo "$PWD"` where available). At the library level, [`pwd`](https://man.openbsd.org/pwd.1) can be implemented by a call to [`getcwd(3)`](https://man.openbsd.org/getcwd.3).

Comment: If `pwd` is read as `present working directory` then both are quite similar, or almost the same IMO.